# How can I group days into weeks?

Tags: r, date

In R, how can I associate between a vector of dates (days) and weeks?

Edit: "weeks" should be the week index within the date range and not within the year. My apologies for the ambiguity.

Comment: take a look at the package `lubridate` which makes handling `dates` very easy. for instance `week(x)` would return the week number of date x.

Comment: -1 Re the edit - so How can we possibly know what you own personal week index is if you don't i) tell us about it earlier, and ii) **show** your data or a snippet it of it?

Comment: @GavinSimpson- you are right. I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you just want the number of completed 7 day intervals since the first record?

```
dvec <- as.Date("2001-04-01")+0:90
dweek <- as.numeric(dvec-dvec[1]) %/% 7
dweek[1:21]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: @GavinSimpson: I "+()-ed" yours too since it was your efforts that provided the basis for deduction. (I now get a popup "Gavin Simpson" when I type "@Gavin". Neat.)

Comment: And you've got to love the the integer division function `%/%` - I'd give another +1 for that if I could - the Answer really is very neat and succinct.

Comment: This also works for datetime (POSIXct) objects, but it's in seconds, so you need to use `%/% (7*24*60*60)`

Comment: Huh...so for Date vectors, this is about 30 times faster than Gavin's method. Gavin's method does relatively better for POSIXlt (only 7 times slower). For POSIXct vectors, this method only very marginally slower, however, Gavin's method is 690 times slower. Not sure if there are any other date-time storage mechanisms. It's a pity, because Gavin's method is more useful - it returns week-of-year, rather than week since starting date..

Comment: You could calculate the starting week once and then add to this result.

Answer (score 23):

For each date, get the week of the year it belongs to by formatting it via `format()` using the `%U` of `%W` format placeholders. `%U` treats Sunday as the first day of the week, whereas `%W` considers Monday to be the first day of the week. Here is an example:

```
now <- as.Date(Sys.time())
dates <- seq(now, now + 25, by = "1 day") 

dat <- data.frame(Dates = dates, Week = format(dates, format = "%W"))
head(dat, 10)
```

Which gives:

```
> head(dat, 10)
        Dates Week
1  2011-11-06   44
2  2011-11-07   45
3  2011-11-08   45
4  2011-11-09   45
5  2011-11-10   45
6  2011-11-11   45
7  2011-11-12   45
8  2011-11-13   45
9  2011-11-14   46
10 2011-11-15   46
```

Although it is unclear from your question exactly what you want to do, a way to match this vector of dates (well, my data frame `dat` above) is via `merge()`. Say we have a vector of weeks we want to match against and some associated data in data frame `weekdat`:

```
weekdat <- data.frame(Week = 44:50, Price = c(10, 20, 25, 30, 20, 15, 10))
```

Then we can link `dat` with `weekdat` using `merge()` as so:

```
> merge(dat, weekdat)
   Week      Dates Price
1    44 2011-11-06    10
2    45 2011-11-07    20
3    45 2011-11-08    20
4    45 2011-11-09    20
5    45 2011-11-10    20
6    45 2011-11-11    20
7    45 2011-11-12    20
8    45 2011-11-13    20
9    46 2011-11-14    25
10   46 2011-11-15    25
11   46 2011-11-16    25
12   46 2011-11-17    25
13   46 2011-11-18    25
14   46 2011-11-19    25
15   46 2011-11-20    25
16   47 2011-11-21    30
17   47 2011-11-22    30
18   47 2011-11-23    30
19   47 2011-11-24    30
20   47 2011-11-25    30
21   47 2011-11-26    30
22   47 2011-11-27    30
23   48 2011-11-28    20
24   48 2011-11-29    20
25   48 2011-11-30    20
26   48 2011-12-01    20
```

There are other ways of matching or linking dates to weeks, but the above should give you something to work from.

Answer (score 9):

strftime is your friend...

```
? strftime # to see the help and the format

set.seed(1)
dates <- Sys.Date() + sample(1:365, size = 10)

R> dates
 [1] "2012-02-11" "2012-03-21" "2012-06-01" "2012-09-30"
 [5] "2012-01-18" "2012-09-25" "2012-10-11" "2012-06-30"
 [9] "2012-06-18" "2011-11-28"

# %j for julian day - number of the day since the 1st of january each year

R> strftime(dates, format = "%j") # or format(dates, format = "%j")
 [1] "042" "081" "153" "274" "018" "269" "285" "182" "170" "332"

R> strftime(dates, format = "%w")
 [1] "6" "3" "5" "0" "3" "2" "4" "6" "1" "1"

# my locale is in French so...
R> strftime(dates, format = "%A")
 [1] "samedi"   "mercredi" "vendredi" "dimanche" "mercredi"
 [6] "mardi"    "jeudi"    "samedi"   "lundi"    "lundi"
```

By the way what do you mean by day, day within the month, the week or the year ?