# How to subset data.frame by weeks and then sum?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

Let's say I have several years worth of data which look like the following

```
# load date package and set random seed
library(lubridate)
set.seed(42)

# create data.frame of dates and income
date <- seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("15-01-2011"), by = "days")
df <- data.frame(date = date, 
                 wday = wday(date),
                 wday.name = wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE),
                 income = round(runif(21, 0, 100)),
                 week = format(date, format="%Y-%U"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#          date wday wday.name income    week
# 1  2010-12-26    1       Sun     91 2010-52
# 2  2010-12-27    2       Mon     94 2010-52
# 3  2010-12-28    3      Tues     29 2010-52
# 4  2010-12-29    4       Wed     83 2010-52
# 5  2010-12-30    5     Thurs     64 2010-52
# 6  2010-12-31    6       Fri     52 2010-52
# 7  2011-01-01    7       Sat     74 2011-00
# 8  2011-01-02    1       Sun     13 2011-01
# 9  2011-01-03    2       Mon     66 2011-01
# 10 2011-01-04    3      Tues     71 2011-01
# 11 2011-01-05    4       Wed     46 2011-01
# 12 2011-01-06    5     Thurs     72 2011-01
# 13 2011-01-07    6       Fri     93 2011-01
# 14 2011-01-08    7       Sat     26 2011-01
# 15 2011-01-09    1       Sun     46 2011-02
# 16 2011-01-10    2       Mon     94 2011-02
# 17 2011-01-11    3      Tues     98 2011-02
# 18 2011-01-12    4       Wed     12 2011-02
# 19 2011-01-13    5     Thurs     47 2011-02
# 20 2011-01-14    6       Fri     56 2011-02
# 21 2011-01-15    7       Sat     90 2011-02
```

I would like to sum 'income' for each week (Sunday thru Saturday). Currently I do the following:

```
Weekending 2011-01-01 = sum(df$income[1:7]) = 487
Weekending 2011-01-08 = sum(df$income[8:14]) = 387
Weekending 2011-01-15 = sum(df$income[15:21]) = 443
```

However I would like a more robust approach which will automatically sum by week. I can't work out how to automatically subset the data into weeks. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to questions. If you want to answer your own question, please do so in an answer (this is encouraged on SO).

Comment: Ahh, ok, I didn't know if that would be bad form. I will add it as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is influenced by @Andrie and @Chase.

```
# load plyr 
library(plyr)

# format weeks as per requirement (replace "00" with "52" and adjust corresponding year)
tmp <- list()
tmp$y <- format(df$date, format="%Y")
tmp$w <- format(df$date, format="%U")
tmp$y[tmp$w=="00"] <- as.character(as.numeric(tmp$y[tmp$w=="00"]) - 1)
tmp$w[tmp$w=="00"] <- "52"
df$week <- paste(tmp$y, tmp$w, sep = "-")

# get summary
df2 <- ddply(df, .(week), summarize, income=sum(income))

# include week ending date
tmp$week.ending <- lapply(df2$week, function(x) rev(df[df$week==x, "date"])[[1]])
df2$week.ending <- sapply(tmp$week.ending, as.character)

#      week income week.ending
# 1 2010-52    487  2011-01-01
# 2 2011-01    387  2011-01-08
# 3 2011-02    443  2011-01-15
```

Answer (score 9):

First use `format` to convert your dates to week numbers, then `plyr::ddply()` to calculate the summaries:

```
library(plyr)
df$week <- format(df$date, format="%Y-%U")
ddply(df, .(week), summarize, income=sum(income))
     week income
1 2011-52    413
2 2012-01    435
3 2012-02    379
```

---

For more information on `format.date`, see `?strptime`, particular the bit that defines `%U` as the week number.

---

**EDIT:**

Given the modified data and requirement, one way is to divide the date by 7 to get a numeric number indicating the week. (Or more precisely, divide by the number of seconds in a week to get the number of weeks since the epoch, which is 1970-01-01 by default.

In code:

```
df$week <- as.Date("1970-01-01")+7*trunc(as.numeric(df$date)/(3600*24*7))
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(week), summarize, income=sum(income))

        week income
1 2010-12-23    298
2 2010-12-30    392
3 2011-01-06    294
4 2011-01-13    152
```

I have not checked that the week boundaries are on Sunday. You will have to check this, and insert an appropriate offset into the formula.

Comment: Almost there, please see edit in my question for an issue I spotted with this approach :)

Comment: thank you kindly. I came up with my own solution based around further reading of ?format and plyr, as you suggested. I changed the data.frame in my question to better reflect what I was after and I think that is why your results are not quite what I was looking for (after applying your code to the new data) but using your answer I was able to get the solution I needed (I have added it above). Thank you very much, I couldn't have done it without reading your approach :)

Answer (score 8):

This is now simple using dplyr.  Also I would suggest using `cut(breaks = "week")` rather than `format()` to cut the dates into weeks.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(week = cut(date, "week")) %>% mutate(weekly_income = sum(income))
```

Answer (score 1):

I Googled "group week days into weeks R" and came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030812/how-can-i-group-days-into-weeks). You mention you have multiple years, so I think we need to keep up with both the week number and also the year, so I modified the answers there as so `format(date, format = "%U%y")`

In use it looks like this:

```
library(plyr) #for aggregating
df <- transform(df, weeknum = format(date, format = "%y%U"))
ddply(df, "weeknum", summarize, suminc = sum(income))
#----
  weeknum suminc
1    1152    413
2    1201    435
3    1202    379
```

See `?strptime` for all the format abbreviations.

Comment: Almost there, please see edit in my question for an issue I spotted with this approach :)

Comment: @TonyBreyal - looks like Andrie beat me to the punch and has a more robust answer. Also, Dwin's answer in the question I linked above is along these lines as well. Cheers.

Comment: thank you kindly for the link. I saw it before but I couldn't work out how it would apply to my requirement of allowing a week to cross the year boundary. I have the solution now though and appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
rollapply(df$income, width=7, FUN = sum, by = 7)
# [1] 487 387 443
```

Or, use `period.sum` from the `xts` package:

```
period.sum(xts(df$income, order.by=df$date), which(df$wday %in% 7))
#            [,1]
# 2011-01-01  487
# 2011-01-08  387
# 2011-01-15  443
```

Or, to get the output in the format you want:

```
data.frame(income = period.sum(xts(df$income, order.by=df$date), 
                               which(df$wday %in% 7)),
           week = df$week[which(df$wday %in% 7)])
#            income    week
# 2011-01-01    487 2011-00
# 2011-01-08    387 2011-01
# 2011-01-15    443 2011-02
```

Note that the first week shows as `2011-00` because that's how it is entered in your data. You could also use `week = df$week[which(df$wday %in% 1)]` which would match your output.

Answer (score 0):

df.index = df['week']   #the the dt variable as index

df.resample('W').sum()    #sum using resample

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(week = as.numeric(date - date[1])%/%7) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(weekincome= sum(income))
```

Instead of date[1] you can have any date from when you want to start your weekly study.