# How to group data in 7 day intervals starting on a particular weekday

Tags: r, group-by

I have been struggling with this a while. How could I group data in 7 day intervals?

Essentially I am trying to **group by a "week" that starts on Friday**. Dates are picked at random within periods between a Friday and the next Thursday. Due to human error there may be not exactly the same number of observations in every period, although normally there should be 7. It is possible that a whole period or two might be missing.

The ideal way would seem to determine a period (i.e. week beginning on Friday) number for each date and then add it to the data set in another column.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   55 obs. of  15 variables:

 $ id           : num  7 8 9 10 11 12 13 16 17 18 ... 
 $ q_0001       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ q_0002       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ q_0003       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ q_0004       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Assm_Date    : Date, format: "2014-01-04" "2014-01-08" "2014-01-08" ...
```

I have cut out the irrelevant variables for the sake of clarity.

**Background:** We are doing a health service improvement project. We take 7 random observations in periods from Fri to next Thu including. So I need to group the answers to questions (i.e. count "yes" in questions 1 to 4) within these 7 day periods.

**How data are produced:** We are looking at 4 quality parameters in hospital cases (about 40 to 50 cases per week). Out of the previous 7 day cases 7 are selected using a RNG. Logistically we can do this on Friday, hence the period - previous Friday to Thursday (i.e. yesterday). We enter data via LimeSurvey interface. For each selected case we enter the case date (Assm_Date) and Yes/No answers to 4 questions (q_0001 to q_0004). I will need to do the operation weekly as we will do a weekly progress chart.

The `*lubridate* week()` method suggested below would be great

```
data$week_starting_friday <- week(data$Assm_Date)+5
```

but unfortunately does not work even if I modify it (see below). I believe this is because that method still determines date's belonging to a certain week on basis Sun-Mon or Mon-Sun and I can't think of a way to ask lubridate to consider week being Fri-Thu.

As the project is still quite small I have an option to every time add the week period number manually in a spreadsheet program, which I might resort to eventually. However it would be great to discover a way to automate the process reliably in R. **Thank you guys for all the answers** - they have been very encouraging and have given new thoughts on how to work with R as I am just learning R.

Comment: Maybe you find some help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8031372/2886003).

Comment: After some hiccups in understanding how this works I tweaked it and - it works!!! I had to put in the correct starting date instead of the first date in the sample, but wonderfully elegant and simple solution - most of it is correct arithmetic and correct data types, using basic knowledge how time is counted in uninterrupted weeks. Thanks a lot, I will put the answer in fully after I've put all data through it. `as.numeric(data$Assm_Date - as.Date("2014-01-03")) %/% 7`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Llopis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2886003/llopis) suggestion I looked  at an example which at first looked difficult to understand. Once I understood it, it was very simple and elegant. Solution to my problem:

```
data$Assmt_Week <- 1+ as.numeric(data$Assm_Date - as.Date("2014-01-03")) %/% 7
```

As a result I get another variable in my dataset which gives me correct week number for each observation. What the above does is it subtracts the period starting date from the assessment date and we get number of days that have passed between these dates. Then we do integer division and know how many full weeks have passed between the assessment date and the original starting date. We also add 1 so that the first week starts on 1 , not 0. Works like a charm.

The original question / solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030812/how-can-i-group-days-into-weeks/8031372#8031372).

```
dvec <- as.Date("2001-04-01")+0:90
dweek <- as.numeric(dvec-dvec[1]) %/% 7
```

Thanks everybody for your advice and help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base solution:

```
# Assumes data is sorted by date
data$week <- cumsum(weekdays(data$Assm_Date) == "Friday")  # highlight week
aggregate(. ~ week, data, function(x) sum(x==1))[-ncol(data)]
```

Counts number of `Yes` by week and question:

```
  week q_0001 q_0002 q_0003 q_0004
1    0      1      2      1      1
2    1      4      1      3      3
3    2      2      2      1      4
4    3      4      3      3      4
5    4      5      3      3      2
6    5      5      4      2      2
7    6      4      4      5      5
8    7      6      4      3      5
9    8      2      1      1      3
```

---

Non base possibilities:

If you use add-on packages like `data.table` (or `dplyr`), you can get fancier:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(data)[, 
  c(
    list(Dates=paste(range(format(Assm_Date, "%b-%d")), collapse=" to ")),
    lapply(
      .SD[, -5, with=F], 
      function(x) paste(names(table(x)), table(x), collapse=";"))
  ),
  by=week
]
```

Produces:

```
   week            Dates     q_0001     q_0002     q_0003     q_0004
1:    0 Jan-01 to Jan-02 No 1;Yes 1 No 2;Yes 0 No 1;Yes 1 No 1;Yes 1
2:    1 Jan-03 to Jan-09 No 4;Yes 3 No 1;Yes 6 No 3;Yes 4 No 3;Yes 4
3:    2 Jan-10 to Jan-16 No 2;Yes 5 No 2;Yes 5 No 1;Yes 6 No 4;Yes 3
4:    3 Jan-17 to Jan-23 No 4;Yes 3 No 3;Yes 4 No 3;Yes 4 No 4;Yes 3
5:    4 Jan-24 to Jan-30 No 5;Yes 2 No 3;Yes 4 No 3;Yes 4 No 2;Yes 5
6:    5 Feb-01 to Jan-31 No 5;Yes 2 No 4;Yes 3 No 2;Yes 5 No 2;Yes 5
7:    6 Feb-07 to Feb-13 No 4;Yes 3 No 4;Yes 3 No 5;Yes 2 No 5;Yes 2
8:    7 Feb-14 to Feb-20 No 6;Yes 1 No 4;Yes 3 No 3;Yes 4 No 5;Yes 2
9:    8 Feb-21 to Feb-24 No 2;Yes 2 No 1;Yes 3 No 1;Yes 3 No 3;Yes 1
```

Here is the data I used:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- as.data.frame(
  c(
    setNames(replicate(4, sample(c("Yes", "No"), 55, r=T), s=F), paste0("q_000", 1:4)),
    Assm_Date=list(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), by="+1 day", len=55))
) )
```

Comment: The base solution gives me insight in some R functions and looks very elegant. Unfortunately the results are not correct. As the dataset at present is quite small I tested this in a spreadsheet. The group totals are correct, but grouping into 7 day periods is not - last "week" has most of observations.

Comment: The more fancy solution also does not give correct results, it seems due to incorrect grouping as well, but in this case understanding of the solution and how to remedy is a bit beyond my reach.

Comment: @r0berts, are you sure the data is sorted by date?  Also, if you look at the added "week" column before aggregation, does it make sense (i.e. does it change every 7 days)?  Without reproducible data it is very hard for me to debug.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I have added a link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10373994/survey_72389_main_data_wk.csv to data sample which I used for testing. There are 55 observations (1 is yes, 2 is no), dates are correct and I have manually added a column named "Week" in Calc - to show that the original dates fall in the 7 day periods starting Friday. I did sort the csv by the date before loading and I also ordered data frame  after loading. I would think that the column added by your method should have same numbers, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

In conjunction with kuba's suggestion, I think you're looking to aggregate weekly observations opposed to daily?

```
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
data <- ...

# this defaults to Sunday, but adding 5 will push it to Friday
data$week_starting_friday <- week(data$Assm_Date) + 5

# isolate non-question columns
notQuestionColumns <- data[, !grepl('q_', names(data))]

# convert Yes/No answers to binary
data <- ifelse(data[, grepl('q_', names(data))] == 'Yes', 1, 0)

# combine non-question columns and data
data <- data.frame(notQuestionColumns, data)

# aggregate answers by week
ddply(data, .(week_starting_friday), numcolwise(sum))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed I am trying to aggregate weekly observations. I am trying this method and I came across that week(x) +5 seems to add 5 to week number of date x, not starting the week on Friday. So instead of weeks starting on Friday I get a regular week number +5 as a value in the data$week_starting_friday

Comment: I think if I do the same a bit modified, it should work:
data$week_starting_friday <- week(data$Assm_Date+days(5))

Comment: Well, no this does not quite work. Not every day + 5 days will get into the correct period. I have checked the original data - all dates comply to 7 observations per week starting on Friday. If the above formula is used we get some weeks with 2 observations and some with 9 or so. I really need to recreate the original 7 day bins - Friday + 6 more days (or 7 days from Friday, inclusive or Friday to next Thursday).

Comment: Hey, sorry for misunderstanding the ask...  Another awesome function in `lubridate` is `floor_date`.  Does `floor_date(data$Assm_Date) + 5` work?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, you have seven different dates in `Assm_Date` and you want to sum all "Yeses" for each date and for each question? In that case you can use `daply` from `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)
dapply(data, .(Assm_Date), summarize, 
  q1 = sum(q_0001 == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE),
  q2 = sum(q_0002 == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, no I have 7 random observation dates within fixed 7 day periods that each start on a Friday. It is within those 7 day periods that I need to summarize data.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a bunch of random dates in a dataframe df:

```
  #Create random dates
  df <- data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-01 11:23"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4))
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-02 01:20"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-02 05:13"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-03 18:22"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-11 16:44"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-11 02:26"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-12 13:13"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2011-11-13 19:33"), by="day", length.out=4), each=4), var=rnorm(4)))
```

You can split it in groups of 7 days as follows:

```
   split(df, cut(strptime(paste(df$date, df$time), format="%F %R"),"7 day"))
```

In your example try something like this:

```
  split(data, cut(strptime(paste(df$Assm_Date), format="%F"),"7 day"))
```

Comment: This is nice, but somehow the grouping is not correct. Most probably the reason is that in the first period the first observation is not on a Friday but on a Saturday. But this is very nice example how one could split data in 7 day intervals. Thanks

Comment: Yes..a quick, rather hacky, workaround is to add an artificial Friday "outlier" data point (e.g. Fri 1-5-1900) to your dataset.  This will align split with Friday, and the first split you can safely ignore.